# Gunicorn restart only while changing a specific file

Tags: python, gunicorn

I need to restart my flask gunicorn only when a specific file changes, by using `--reload` any file change will restart gunicorn but I need to restart gunicorn only when a file i mentioned changes.

Is there any way to do this?